# Is there any way to lock length of edge? or at least location of vertices?

Tags: modeling, transforms

[image]

As you can see, there are 6m edges in my blend file. I want to set length of another edges next to these 6 m ones, but everytime i do that, it transforms 6 m edges too! i tried to fix this with hide function, but even i hided the faces of 6 m ones, it transformed hidden faces size too... :(

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to obtain equidistant divisions could be:

- first dissolve the inner edges

[image]

- select the edges along the mesh

[image]

- Assign the length multiplied by the number of divisions we want, in this case 4 divisions.

[image]

- And divide the faces again with Ctrl+R, that way we get all the edges of 6m each

[image]

Also, if we want the longer edges to be smoother, we can soften them in the "Loop Tools" panel with the "Relax" button, press it a few times, and now we can assign the length of the edges.

[image]